# QPainterPath painting arc

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and I have a problem painting an arc with QPainterPath. When I'm painting it, also it paints a line to some end of the rectangular.Why it is painting some line?[image]

This is my code:

```
QRectF rect( m_height / 2 - 100.0 / 2, m_width / 2 - 100.0 / 2, 100.0, 100.0 );
path.moveTo( m_width / 2, m_height / 2 );
path.arcTo( rect, 90, - 180 );
QPainter painter( this );
painter.drawPath( path );
```

I was planning to draw something like this:
[image]

Code to this:

```
// figure coords
    QRectF rectangle1( m_x * m_scale, m_y * m_scale, m_width * m_scale, m_height * m_scale );
int startAngle1 = 90 * 16 ;
int spanAngle1 = 180 * 16;

path.arcTo( rectangle1, startAngle1, spanAngle1 );

QRectF rectangle2( ( m_x + 170.0 ) * m_scale, m_y * m_scale, m_width * m_scale, m_height * m_scale );
int startAngle2 = 90 * 16;
int spanAngle2 = -180 * 16;

path.arcTo( rectangle2, startAngle2, spanAngle2 );

QLine line1( ( m_x + 125.0 ) * m_scale, m_y * m_scale, ( m_x + 295.0 ) * m_scale, m_y * m_scale );
QLine line2( ( m_x + 125.0 ) * m_scale, ( m_y + 250.0) * m_scale, ( m_x + 295.0 ) * m_scale,
             ( m_y + 250.0) * m_scale );



// paint figure

QPainter painter(this);
painter.drawArc(rectangle1, startAngle1, spanAngle1);
painter.drawArc(rectangle2, startAngle2, spanAngle2);
painter.drawLine( line1 );
painter.drawLine( line2 );
```

Why I used QPainterPath? Cause you can easily fill it with color, which I need later, when I want to fill with color second picture, you need to calculate, what pixels to color( or I don't know something ).
So the question is, what I wrote at the top, why is this line is also drawn, when I use 
path.arcto(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made it too complicated. There is a method [drawRoundedRect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#drawRoundedRect) and it will do the job.

```
QPainter painter(this);
QRect r(internalPartOfRect.adjusted(-r.height()/2, 0, r.height()/2, 0));
painter.setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::WindowText));
painter.drawRoundedRect(r, r.height()/2);
```

Comment: Thx for answering, but 1 more thing, how I centralize this thing?:) I was doing it like this ( screensizeX / 2 - internalPart.width / 2 - internalPart.height / 4 ), but this doesn't work , I'd do ( screensizeX / 2 - r.width / 2 ) but I don't know about the coords yet. Or is there's a way to move already created rect?

Comment: if you want fill entire widget then replace second and third line with: `QRect r(rect());`, you can also add some margins like that: `r.adjust(margin, margin, -margin, -margin);`

Comment: This is an excellent solution. However, if you ever want to add the functionality to have the squircle drawn during the `mouseMoveEvent()`, you'll end up with square corners behind the squircle. I recommend using a `QPainterPath` instead under those circumstances.